# Angular Universal and ngx-datable configuration

Tags: angular, angular-universal, ngx-datatable

I'm trying to transform some old app to Angular universal(with Angular 9) and I'm having a problem with the configuration of ngx-datable to work with server-side rendering.
I was following official guidance how to configure it https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/docs/universal/server-side-rendering.md

But I'm having a problem with the placement of providers

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: ScrollbarHelper,
    useClass: ServerScrollBarHelper
  },
  {
    provide: DimensionsHelper,
    useClass: ServerDimensionsHelper
  }
];
```

My `AppRoutingModule` is lazy-loading other submodules with `loadChildren`.
I'm also using `SharedModule` where most of my client-side providers are defined.

I found out I can only access `ServerScrollBarHelper` and `ServerDimensionsHelperthem` if I define them inside submodules but the problem is that they should only work when Angular server-side rendering is happening. I tried to put them inside `AppServerModule` providers list but then it's like they are not defined.

Is there any example of this, or is anybody knows how I can easily load different providers for server-rendering and client-rendering without changing my app structure too much?

EDIT: so I narrowed down my problem to lazy-loading, because with layz-loading modules you can't override your providers from `AppRoutingModule` because every module uses his own Injector. I still can't find a solution to this without removing lazy-loading from the project which doesn't sound right.

Comment: I think you could use a factory to load the correct implementation based on the platform

Answer (score 0):

My current solution to this problem.

In every lazy-loaded module, I injected `ServerScrollBarHelper` & `ServerDimensionsHelper` so I could access them even when lazy loading. But I changed their code so they behave differently on the server and inside the browser.

```
   import { Injectable, Inject, Injector, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { DimensionsHelper } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class ServerDimensionsHelper extends DimensionsHelper {

    clientRqst;
    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object, injectctor: Injector) {
        super();
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            this.clientRqst = injectctor.get(REQUEST);
        }
    }

    getDimensions(element: Element): ClientRect {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            return super.getDimensions(element);
        } else {
            console.log(this.clientRqst.headers);
            const width = parseInt(this.clientRqst.headers.cookie['CH-DW'], 10) || 1000;
            const height = parseInt(this.clientRqst.headers.cookie['CH-DH'], 10) || 800;

            const adjustedWidth = width;
            const adjustedHeight = height;

            return {
                height: adjustedHeight,
                bottom: 0,
                top: 0,
                width: adjustedWidth,
                left: 0,
                right: 0
            };
        }
    }
}




import { ScrollbarHelper } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class ServerScrollBarHelper extends ScrollbarHelper {
    width: number;

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
        super(document);
        this.width = 16; // use default value
    }

    getWidth(): number {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            return super.getWidth();
        } else {
            return this.width;
        }

    }
}
```